# pass data from one page to another using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would think this has been answered a bunch but I can't seem to get it to work. I am able to save the variables from one page, but it doesn't seem to be passing the string value into the div in the other page.

```
function pass(e) {

    var main= $('#main').text(),

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: main,
        success: function () {
            window.location = '/Main/Subpage';
            $('#nextDiv').html(main);
        }
    });
}
```

Going through developer tools, it looks like it passes the variable into the ajax call, but when the next page loads, in the #nextDiv div, no string is placed there. I don't use PHP and am using jquery.

Comment: Because you need to store somehow the data at server side, for example in database or in a session variable. Ant the next page then you should retreive that data. So `ajax -> data store -> redirect -> receive data -> update div`.

Comment: im getting the data from the database already, so how do i send that data to another page then?

Comment: If you store your data in database already, then you using some server side language. What is that? Anyway, when you rendering page, you can fetch that data from database...

Comment: using C#, but I only work on the front-end of it, is there no way for me to store the data just by using the front-end language or do I need to write some method or class that stores it from the backend

Comment: if this is just a temporary data, and you have access only for the front-end, then use local storage, or cookies.